# Coming from Perl/DBI to Python

Tags: python, database

From an absolute Python n00b:

Years after falling in love with Perl's DBI `fetchall_hashref()` I've come to Python to do some similar db work.

What I found so far is that
`res.fetchall()` returns a row in which the columns are not indexed with the column name. I have to use row[0], row[0] and so on. Kind of like Perl's fetchall.

So I started to look for Pythons equivalent to fetchall_hashref() and came up blank.

Is it not there in Python land?

BTW, reread and thought it needed some clarification

Perl's `fetchall_hashref()` return a hashreference (as the name implies). You can access a certain column field with the column name, i.e.: `$row->{'column_name'}`

Comment: The default row type is a list of tuples. Many connector packages provide a way to configure a cursor that returns a list of dictionaries (or hashmaps), but the precise syntax for doing this varies by package.

Comment: I think you want to look for `DictCursor`. In Python more often than not we use some ORM, so I won't recall the details for it for each different DB.